# How to use INDEX and MATCH in VBA + Excel with multiple criterias?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, match

I have a sheet with some tabs, which in the first one  there is the following table:

[image: Tab1 - Table 1]

In the second tab I type the "cliente" and "tipo" fields, and I'd like to get the ID as return.

I'm using the following code:

```
tipo = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
cliente = Range("D5").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Tab 1").[Table1[ID]], WorksheetFunction.Match(cliente & tipo, Sheets("Tab 1").[Table1[CLIENTE]] & Sheets("Tab 1").[Table1[TIPO]], 0))
```

I don't know exactly what's wrong, but I've tried with a lots of ways, including some examples spliting the code and using Evaluate function as well. But, nothing happens.

How could I do it?

Comment: have a look at the [world grand master of Excel INDEX/MATCH](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/how-to-use-index-match-part-1.html) - you might find what you're looking for

Comment: You can do with array formula, with out code.

Comment: You might also want to consider using a PivotTable and Slicers...might be easier for users to click on Slicers and have the PivotTable filtered accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `=INDEX(MATCH, MATCH)` is not an array formula, but a normal one. However, your case is different - you are not matching rows and columns, but two columns, thus it should be. Array formulas are implented with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you have your data like this:

[image]

Then this is the Array Formula in G1:

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(1,(E1=B1:B6)*(F1=C1:C6),0))
```

And this is how to do it with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba):

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Range("G1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(1,(E1=B1:B6)*(F1=C1:C6),0))"
End Sub
```

To see how this formula is working, see the calculation of Excel in the Formula>Evaluation tab (`VERGLEICH` is `MATCH` in German):

[image]

Comment: That's returning the incorrect ID though isn't it Vityata? As per OP's requirement, in your example case, it should return 1.. shouldn't it?

Comment: @Zac - thank you for the comment, I have changed the answer to a correct one.

Comment: I knew I had some use :)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use regular formulas for something like this.

Assuming that Columns A, B, and C are laid out as per your example and that the lookup value for Cliente is in F1 and Tipo is in F2, this would be a formula not entered as an array:

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,INDEX(MATCH(1,(F1=B1:B6)*(F2=C1:C6),0),1))
```

This would be the equivalent array formula (entered with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]):

```
{=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(1,(F1=B1:B6)*(F2=C1:C6),0))}
```

See below....

[image: Array Version]

[image: Non-array Version]

Comment: The two indexes, avoiding the array formula are impressive.

Comment: I find that I am my own worst enemy when it comes to array formulas.  I have fat-fingered them so many times that I use a special color for them in some spreadsheets.

Comment: Noone likes array formulas, they cause too many problems. I would rather convince someone to use VBA than write one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use max if in an array formula

```
=MAX(IF(Table1[[#All],[CLIENTE]]=A2,IF(Table1[[#All],[TIPO]]=B2,Table1[[#All],[ID]])))
```

Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Data]

Comment: Did you try the above at all?

Answer (score 0):

In the other tab, go to cell `A1` and type in

```
='Tab 1'!B1&":"&'Tab 1'!C1
```

copy and paste it to the whole `A` column.

In cell `B1` enter `CD` or other Cliente value. In cell `B2` enter `D` or other TIPO value. In `B3` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Tab 1'!A:A,MATCH(B1&":"&B2,A:A,0)), "Not found!")
```

You should get the result in `B3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a programmatic solution, you can just iterate over both tabs with a VBA program rather than a formula.

In the VBA Editor, place this code in the area of your first sheet, for example "Sheet 1" or whatever you have. Don't place it in ThisWorkbook area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change() 

Dim client As String
Dim type As String
Dim client2 As String
Dim type2 As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastRowSheet2 As Integer

' Assuming your sheet is setup similar to Vityata's answer
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
lastRowSheet2 = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

For row = 1 to lastRow
    client = Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row).Value
    type = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & row).Value

    For row2 = 1 to lastRowSheet2
        client2 = Worksheets(2).Range("B" & row2).Value
        type2 = Worksheets(2).Range("C" & row2).Value

        If client = client2 And type = type2 Then
            Worksheets(1).Range("A" & row).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & row2).Value 
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Of course, you will need to change the 'A's, 'B's, and 'C's to fit your workbook and desired ranges. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for supporting me.
I started trying by the [Vityata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata) suggestion and it worked.

My final code is: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table1[ID],MATCH(1,(" & cliente & "=Table1[CLIENTE])*(" & valor & "=Table1[TIPO]),0))"`