# Excel - Cross Reference - Different Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 different sheets for the excel document -- 1. County Lookup by Zip Code, 2. County Recording Fees, 3. ZipCode

What I a trying to achieve is the user will enter the Zipcode on the sheet 'County Lookup by Zipcode' and then it will look for the county name on the 'ZipCode' sheet and then it will grab the Recording Fee off the sheet name 'County Recoding Fees'

Issue is that counties in different states in the US have the same name so it is pulling in the wrong fee amount.

I've tried VLOOKUP with no luck.

Link to sheet --
https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://docs.google.com/file/d/1LwvPLmgL9DUT0aopnuNMYJTzksHT8Xn_/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel__;!!KurxxnpmNnI!ViU4pth0-f26aMXJFfiBzD8ktnisXsL7PC_vfDdWCaLx832109gGj0bx2v8jq6UDv-Eqfg$

Comment: Instead of images could you upload a workbook to a file sharing site and post a link?

Comment: You need to do a lookup by county name and state. You could create a new column which concatenates the two an then lookup against that, or you can use INDEX and MATCH in an array formula (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426054/how-to-use-index-and-match-in-vba-excel-with-multiple-criterias)

Comment: You could use formulas to get the state and county for the zipcode then use them in a SUMPRODUCT function to return the Recording Fee..

Comment: @norie -- added link to spreadsheet

Comment: There is no county named 'Hartford' on the 'County Recording Fees' sheet. If I filter the Agency column for 'Hartford' I get 7 partial matches, 5 in Connecticut and one in Vermont. Could something else be used to get the fee? Perhaps the FIPSCode?

Comment: @norie -- I was using B2&"*" to place a wildcard at the end and was able to find it using VLookup but the only issue is that with other counties it'll pull in the first result if there more than one with the same name.

Comment: I guess it would be best to filter by the State and Wildcard but not sure how to achieve that with the Index and Match option.

Answer (score 0):

The data on the the County Recording Fees tab seems incomplete.  For example, there is no data for Los Angeles County.  Maybe that is ok?

Also the County Recording Fees seems to have data rows for each city and town in a given county. For example, in the case of zip code 6042, the count_fips is 9003.  There are 31 rows on the County Recording Fees with a value of 09003. Maybe that is is ok, too?

All that said, you can use nested [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)s to find the data you want.

I put my formulas in row A4 on the County Lookup by Zipcode tab.

In A4, `6042`

In B4, `=XLOOKUP(A4,ZipCode!A2:A33122,ZipCode!L2:L33122,"Not Found")`

In C4, `=XLOOKUP(A4,ZipCode!A2:A33122,ZipCode!E2:E33122,"Not Found")`

In D4,

```
=XLOOKUP(
         TEXT(XLOOKUP(A4,ZipCode!A2:A33122,ZipCode!K2:K33122,"Not Found"),"00000"),
         'County Recording Fees'!C2:C3204,'County Recording Fees'!E2:E3204
        )
```

The first look up grabs the value in the 'county_fips' column on the Zip Code tab and converts the value to text.  Then that value is used to look up the 'FIPS Code' on the County Recording Fees tab in column C, the return value is the 'FirstPageFee' in Column E.

in E4,

```
=XLOOKUP(
         TEXT(XLOOKUP(A4,ZipCode!A2:A33122,ZipCode!K2:K33122,"Not Found"),"00000"),
         'County Recording Fees'!C2:C3204,'County Recording Fees'!G2:G3204
         )
```

[image: Screen shot of the formula results]

Comment: Thank you for that! It does work however some zip codes could possibly have two counties for example this zip code 13141, on the zipcode sheet if you look under the column County_name_all you'll see Courtland|Onondaga. 

Would you be able to show how to have both of those counites and fees shown if a zipcode has more than one county listed?

Comment: If you want to return the data from the County_name_all column, Column N on the zip code tab, update the formula in B4 to be, `=XLOOKUP(A4,ZipCode!A2:A33122,ZipCode!N2:N33122,"Not Found")`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to have the formula look up the recording fee for each county if there is more than one, in this case for zip code 13141 would need it to display the fee for Courtland and Onondaga, and just have each of those listed on a new row?

Comment: I found about one-third of the rows on the Zip Code tab have multiple counties. You are going to need to transform that data such that there is one row per county.  Which would mean non-unique rows by zip.  On a new zip code tab there would be two rows for 13141 one for Cortland and another for Onondaga. Make sure to also grab their corresponding FIPS numbers. Then I would grab the data from the other table for the fees using XLOOKUP. Finally once you have all the data you need in one table, use the FILTER function to return all the rows from your new table that match the entered zip code.

Comment: Would you be able to help with an example? I’m not too savvy with excel

Comment: I would create a new data table (you might have to find a new source) that has **one row for each county** in the US.  To start, the columns ought to be, `County Name`, `County State`, `County FIPS`, `Zip Code`. (Let me know when you have this and I can help with the next steps.) Then, you can add two look up columns to that table using the XLOOKUP function to grab the recording data you want using the FIPS as the look up value.  Finally, on your first tab, you can use the  FILTER function to return the one or more rows from your new data table matching a particular zip code.